# Add a custom property to object (i.e. Textbox) within a form at run time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

is there a simple way to add a custom property (i.e. a TextBox1) in a form at run time? What I mean is to avoid creating and using *custom controls*, just adding custom properties to the standard one.

...so that it can be then set and accessed like

```
Me.TextBox1.MyCustomProperty = "my string or value"
```

Let's say in the similar way like working with structures:

```
Public Structure uAccess
    Dim isEditable As Boolean
    Dim isKoopPrice As Boolean
    Dim isUserEditable As Boolean
    Dim isManagerEditable As Boolean
End Structure

Dim Col1Access As uAccess

    With Col1Access    
        .isEditable = False
        .isManagerEditable = False
        .isSalePrice = False
        .isUserEditable = False
    End With
```

Best regards,

Libor

Comment: you arent *adding* fields to that structure, just *setting* them

Comment: Well, the point is, that you can include another line (property) like "Dim MyLine as String" and then use "Col1Access.Myline = 'My text'...

Comment: But you cant do that at *runtime* which was the question.  Since property you want to add  cant and wont change the TB's behavior at all, it isnt really a property, but a variable of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

Add it to the `.Tag` property of the `Textbox` since it is an `Object` you can store anything in it.

```
Dim col1Access As New uAccess
With Col1Access    
    .isEditable = False
    .isManagerEditable = False
    .isSalePrice = False
    .isUserEditable = False
End With
Textbox1.Tag = col1Access ' know as boxing
```

Get the object back:

```
Dim ua As uAccess = TryCast(Textbox1.Tag, uAccess) ' unboxing 
If ua IsNot Nothing Then
  'use the ua object now
End If
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm already using the Tag to store database reference, but this answer deserves a vote. I might re-structure the data in favor of boxing.

Comment: Why not store all the data you need in one object - add the db stuff to it?

Comment: That's what I do at the moment, I have an array of a structure with Dims. So I call MyStructureArray(i).MyProperty1 (each array corresponds to one column in datagridview). I just wanted to know, if there's a simpler way, without defining extra objects (and there's loads of them generated this way).

Comment: I think that should be a different question. It is too large a topic to just tack along to this. You need to describe very well what you are doing and why you need this array(i.e. how and why it's accessed) and we could poss get you a better design idea.